# Finding elements after the DOM has been changed

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a list of addresses that are grouped by US State. The state names are H4 tags and the addresses are li tags in one unordered list per state. Some of the addresses are special, and are designated with the class name "partner".

I have a checkbox on the page that, when checked, will toggle all the partner locations off and on via jQuery. If a particular state has all its locations hidden, I want that state's H4 tag to be hidden as well. My thought was to search the DOM for all the parent containers with no li children, and then hide them, but I don't know how to get jQuery to find them, now that the DOM has been changed. Maybe I'm going about this all wrong.

`javascript` tried:

```js
var partner = $('.partner');

$('#include-partner-locations').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    partner.fadeIn(500);
  } else {
    partner.fadeOut(500);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #333;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#address-directory {
  font-size: 13px;
}
li.location-name {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.map {
  padding: 3px 8px 6px 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #333333;
  display: inline-block;
}
.partner:after {
  content: ' *';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div style="float:right; margin-top:25px; font-size:11px;">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="include-partner-locations">
  <label for="include-partner-locations">Include partner locations</label>
</div>

<p style="clear:both;">* Partner location</p>

<div id="address-directory">


  <section>
    <h4>Arizona</h4>

    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="location-name">Phoenix
        <br>817 East Indian School Road
        <br>Phoenix, AZ&nbsp;&nbsp;85014
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=817+East+Indian+School+Road+Phoenix+85014+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Tempe
        <br>1775 W. University Drive
        <br>Tempe, AZ&nbsp;&nbsp;85281
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1775+W.+University+Drive+Tempe+85281+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name partner">Tucson
        <br>234 East 6th Street
        <br>Tucson, AZ&nbsp;&nbsp;85705
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=234+East+6th+Street+Tucson+85705+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Tucson
        <br>2903 E. Broadway Blvd.
        <br>Tucson, AZ&nbsp;&nbsp;85716
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=2903+E.+Broadway+Blvd.+Tucson+85716+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>


  <section>
    <h4>Florida</h4>

    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="location-name partner">Coral Gables
        <br>275 University Drive
        <br>Coral Gables, FL&nbsp;&nbsp;33134
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=275+University+Drive+Coral+Gables+33134+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name partner">Fort Lauderdale
        <br>801 N. Andrews Ave.
        <br>Fort Lauderdale, FL&nbsp;&nbsp;33311
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=801+N.+Andrews+Ave.+Fort+Lauderdale+33311+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name partner">Maitland
        <br>160 Candace Drive
        <br>Maitland, FL&nbsp;&nbsp;32751
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=160+Candace+Drive+Maitland+32751+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name partner">Miami
        <br>7451 SW 50th Terrace
        <br>Miami, FL&nbsp;&nbsp;33155
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=7451+SW+50th+Terrace+Miami+33155+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h4>Arkansas</h4>

    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="location-name">Bentonville
        <br>3204 Moberly Lane
        <br>Bentonville, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72712
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=3204+Moberly+Lane+Bentonville+72712+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Conway
        <br>1101 Museum Road
        <br>Conway, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72032
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1101+Museum+Road+Conway+72032+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Fayetteville
        <br>20 Township
        <br>Fayetteville, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72703
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=20+Township+Fayetteville+72703+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Ft. Smith
        <br>906 Towson Avenue
        <br>Ft. Smith, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72901
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=906+Towson+Avenue+Ft.+Smith+72901+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Little Rock
        <br>815 Main
        <br>Little Rock, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72201
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=815+Main+Little+Rock+72201+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you include `html` , `css` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: Here's a simplified version. Florida has no partner locations, so I want the header "Florida" to disappear along with its locations when the box is unchecked. https://jsfiddle.net/krishunt/rn2vw1mq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your JavaScript to the following:

```
$('#include-partner-locations').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("h4").fadeIn(500);
        $(".partner").fadeIn(500);
    }
    else {
        $("section").each(function(index) {
            $(".partner").fadeOut(500);
            if ($(this).children("ul").children(".location-name").length == $(this).children("ul").children(".partner").length) {
                $(this).children("h4").fadeOut(500);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You had a couple of typos in your code (an extra bracket and a missing $), but once I got them sorted out, it worked beautifully.

Comment: Sorry about the typos. I fixed them in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` , `.get()` , `.every()`, `.promise()` , `.prev()`  to filter `ul` elements where every `li` descendant element has `style` `display` equal to `"none"` when all `.partner` elements have completed animations; call `.fadeOut()` on previous element sibling `h4` of filtered `ul` element

```js
var partner = $('.partner');

$('#include-partner-locations').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    partner.fadeIn(500);
    $("h4").fadeIn(500)
  } else {
    var ul;
    partner.fadeOut(500, function() {
      ul = $("ul").filter(function(i, el) {
        return $("li", this).get().every(function(elem) {
          return elem.style.display === "none"
        })
      })

    })

    partner.promise().then(function() {
      ul.prev("h4").fadeOut()
    })

  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #333;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
#address-directory {
  font-size: 13px;
}
li.location-name {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.map {
  padding: 3px 8px 6px 8px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #333333;
  display: inline-block;
}
.partner:after {
  content: ' *';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div style="float:right; margin-top:25px; font-size:11px;">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="include-partner-locations">
  <label for="include-partner-locations">Include partner locations</label>
</div>

<p style="clear:both;">* Partner location</p>

<div id="address-directory">


  <section>
    <h4>Arizona</h4>

    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="location-name">Phoenix
        <br>817 East Indian School Road
        <br>Phoenix, AZ&nbsp;&nbsp;85014
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=817+East+Indian+School+Road+Phoenix+85014+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Tempe
        <br>1775 W. University Drive
        <br>Tempe, AZ&nbsp;&nbsp;85281
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1775+W.+University+Drive+Tempe+85281+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name partner">Tucson
        <br>234 East 6th Street
        <br>Tucson, AZ&nbsp;&nbsp;85705
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=234+East+6th+Street+Tucson+85705+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Tucson
        <br>2903 E. Broadway Blvd.
        <br>Tucson, AZ&nbsp;&nbsp;85716
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=2903+E.+Broadway+Blvd.+Tucson+85716+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>


  <section>
    <h4>Florida</h4>

    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="location-name partner">Coral Gables
        <br>275 University Drive
        <br>Coral Gables, FL&nbsp;&nbsp;33134
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=275+University+Drive+Coral+Gables+33134+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name partner">Fort Lauderdale
        <br>801 N. Andrews Ave.
        <br>Fort Lauderdale, FL&nbsp;&nbsp;33311
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=801+N.+Andrews+Ave.+Fort+Lauderdale+33311+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name partner">Maitland
        <br>160 Candace Drive
        <br>Maitland, FL&nbsp;&nbsp;32751
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=160+Candace+Drive+Maitland+32751+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name partner">Miami
        <br>7451 SW 50th Terrace
        <br>Miami, FL&nbsp;&nbsp;33155
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=7451+SW+50th+Terrace+Miami+33155+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section>
    <h4>Arkansas</h4>

    <ul class="clearfix">
      <li class="location-name">Bentonville
        <br>3204 Moberly Lane
        <br>Bentonville, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72712
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=3204+Moberly+Lane+Bentonville+72712+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Conway
        <br>1101 Museum Road
        <br>Conway, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72032
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=1101+Museum+Road+Conway+72032+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Fayetteville
        <br>20 Township
        <br>Fayetteville, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72703
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=20+Township+Fayetteville+72703+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Ft. Smith
        <br>906 Towson Avenue
        <br>Ft. Smith, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72901
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=906+Towson+Avenue+Ft.+Smith+72901+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>

      <li class="location-name">Little Rock
        <br>815 Main
        <br>Little Rock, AR&nbsp;&nbsp;72201
        <br>
        <a class="map" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=815+Main+Little+Rock+72201+United%20States">map</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>

</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rn2vw1mq/2/

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your time!